# Optimum way to train a keras nn by a dataset

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have a training dataset with all the images and no sub -directories , also the images are named as random long ids and the target labels are stored in another file labels.txt with ids and the corresponding  labels. 
How should I implement a generator using keras to pass these images to the model without loading the dataset in ram.

edit:

One way I see it as

sorting the image names and labels so that i can use ImageDataGenerator.flow

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running a script before even using Keras just to clean up your data into a more standard format such as `.h5`. You can then bin this data into batches with a given index in the key id. Then writing the `DataGenerator` in Keras becomes extremely easy.

The way I do it is to have the following type of keys:

`dataset_identifier_ix`

where dataset is either **train**, **validation** or **test**, depending on the set you wish to use. Identifier in your case will be either **image** and **label**. Lastly, **ix** is the batch index. Inside each of these batches you have $n$ instances with which to train your model.

If this is the structure of your `.h5`, then the `DataGenerator` code can be like

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, dataset, filename, X_identifier, Y_identifier, 
                 batch_size, percent_data_use = 1, shuffle=True):
        super(DataGenerator,self).__init__()

        with h5py.File(filename+'.h5', 'r') as hf:
            keys = list(hf.keys())
            # Get dimensions of the input space
            temp = [i for i in keys if dataset+'_'+X_identifier in i]
            x_dims = hf[temp[0]].shape[1::]
            num_files = len(temp)
            # Get dimensions of the output space
            temp = [i for i in keys if dataset+'_'+Y_identifier in i]
            y_dims = hf[temp[0]].shape[1::]

        # The batch size
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_files = num_files
        # Assumes the file ids are always from 0 to num_files
        self.file_ids = list(range(int(percent_data_use*num_files)))
        # Calculate the number of batches
        self.num_batches = int(percent_data_use*num_files)

        self.filename = filename
        self.dataset = dataset 
        self.X_identifier = X_identifier
        self.Y_identifier = Y_identifier

        # Dimensions of the input and the output
        self.x_dims = x_dims
        self.y_dims = y_dims
        self.input_shape = (int(x_dims[0]*sampling_percent),) + x_dims[1:]

        self.sampling_percent = sampling_percent
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        if shuffle is True: self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        """Number of batch in the Sequence.

        Returns
            The number of batches in the Sequence.
        """
        return self.num_batches

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Gets batch at position `index`.
        Arguments
            index: position of the batch in the Sequence.
        Returns
            A batch
        """        
        X = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.x_dims)
        Y = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.y_dims)

        with h5py.File(self.filename+'.h5', 'r') as hf:

            # Input and output identifiers
            x_id = self.dataset + '_' + \
                    self.X_identifier + '_' + str(self.file_ids[index])
            y_id = self.dataset + '_' + \
                    self.Y_identifier + '_' + str(self.file_ids[index])

            X = np.asarray(hf[x_id])
            Y = np.asarray(hf[y_id]) 

        if len(X) == 0:
            return None

        ## Restructure X, and Y for use in the Keras network
        return X, Y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.file_ids)
```